# Validate date in MM/YYYY format in momentjs

Tags: knockout.js, momentjs

How can I change this code to accept both mm/dd/yyyy and mm/yyyy dates?   We have one page in our app where the requirements are dates in mm/yyyy format and the rest are mm/dd/yyyy.

The mm/yyyy dates are failing validation.

```
ko.validation.rules["simpleDate"] = {
    validator: (val: any, validate: any) => {
        if (val == null) return true;

        return moment(val).isValid();
    },
    message: "Invalid date"
};





eventDate: KnockoutObservable<Date> = ko.observable(null).extend({ required: { message: "Please enter an event date." }, simpleDate: { message: "Please enter a valid event date." } });
lawsuitDate: KnockoutObservable<Date> = ko.observable(null).extend({ required: { message: "Please enter a lawsuit date." }, simpleDate: { message: "Please enter a valid lawsuit date." } });
```

EDIT:

I added a separate validation method and tried this and it's still not working.  Any ideas?

```
ko.validation.rules["simpleDate2"] = {
    validator: (val: any, validate: any) => {
        if (val == null) return true;

        return moment(val,'MM/YYYY').isValid();
    },
    message: "Invalid date"
};

        eventDate: KnockoutObservable<Date> = ko.observable(null).extend({ required: { message: "Please enter an event date." }, simpleDate2: { message: "Please enter a valid event date." } });
        lawsuitDate: KnockoutObservable<Date> = ko.observable(null).extend({ required: { message: "Please enter a lawsuit date." }, simpleDate2: { message: "Please enter a valid lawsuit date." } });
```

2nd edit:

It's the **required** validation message that is showing
Please enter an event date.
Please enter a lawsuit date.

Comment: This seems more like a `momentjs` question than a knockout issue

Comment: I think you may need to create two different ko validation rules for the different formats, and then use those formats as the 2nd parameter in the call to moment

Comment: You could simply check the string confirms to the 2 digit, slash, 4 digit pattern with a regex and if it does supply `01` as the missing day and then use moment to validate it.

Comment: Definitely agree with @JamesThorpe that if some of your fields are supposed to be `mm/dd/yyyy` and some are supposed to be `mm/yyyy`, then you have TWO different validation rules and you should keep them separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moment accepts an array of formats the string is expected to be parsed with ([String + Formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/)).  Change your validator to use it.  You'll also want to enable strict parsing so it must match one of the formats.

```
ko.validation.rules["simpleDate"] = {
    validator: (val: any, validate: any) => {
        if (val == null) return true;

        return moment(val, ['MM/DD/YYYY', 'MM/YYYY'], true).isValid();
    },
    message: "Invalid date"
};
```

Comment: Whilst this works, it won't help the UI to show what is actually acceptable for each field, and given they're different on the same page, I'd probably want to show the acceptable format as part of the message.

Comment: The message is overridden to something that doesn't involve the expected formats anyway. For a general solution, I would approach this much differently, but for this case, the added complexities would be unnecessary.